# Term or phrase (bygone era) where doodles were part and parcel to writing

Tags: expressions, terminology, typography

I read something a while back talking about this.  It was a term or phrase I had to lookup; and it was available via Google-Bing, but not “predominant” - not a universal thing.

Not exactly back in the times of the monks: writing flamboyant first characters that take up perhaps 5% of the page (and perhaps 80% of the artistic effort), but I don't think it precludes that.

The context of what I read was more along the lines of turn of the century efforts; perhaps some kind of art nouveau fad.  Flowery flourishes. Itself perhaps an echo of 18th century penmanship – calligraphy++.

When a letter to someone was more than just text; and more than the craftsmanship of excellent handwriting.

I think of it like putting a big squiggle under a paragraph (elongated sideways “S”) with two lines through the middle like a dollar sign.  That is a minor instantiation of what I'm talking about.  The term captures that and much more.

Occasionally you'll see examples online, where the author will have an obscure dingbat glyph at the bottom that kind of captures the thing.

Comment: I saw something about that on TV years ago, it said that often the monks or whoever was writing/illustrating the book would add in little parts in the illustrations depicting some sort of pornographic scene. Can't remember what the style was called, maybe it'll come to me later.

Comment: Is this link the sort of thing you mean http://io9.com/bizarre-and-vulgar-illustrations-from-illuminated-medie-1456202572

Comment: @Frank - The term did not innately signify anything pornographic or subversive.  More to do with what we've lost (limitations) in a pure-text based era.  Nor did it really have to do directly with "illustrations" as aids - - more like simple flowery embellishments of mood.

Comment: Maybe I'd gone too far with _marginalia_, but now I've found it on the internet that's my evenings filled. Thank you for misdirecting me to it.

Comment: _”Marginalia”_ is worthy; and will be - perhaps - the first thing I remember a few weeks on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may be referring to **[flourished writing](https://www.google.it/search?q=flourish%20writing&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=GCp5U9nsNoXT4QSskID4BA&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=768&bih=928)**:

- An ornamental flowing curve in handwriting or scrollwork:
  letters with an emphatic flourish beneath them

Comment: Yes – that best describes it!  (Although the actual term was something more animated, like _"gilded rubrication"_ or something obscure (I just made that up.  Not it.)  [L.M. Kelchner](http://www.designsponge.com/2010/07/past-present-handwriting-and-flourish-art.html), apparently, was the boss.  I like _"Flourish writing"_ vs. _"Flourished writing"_ - but then I'm an idiot.  Lots of recon to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Bullantic**: capitalized and ornamented, as letters used on papal bulls or {Bullantic letters}, Gothic letters used in papal bulls. [1913 Webster]

The ornamental letter, or the *first characters that take up perhaps 5% of the page (and perhaps 80% of the artistic effort)* is a **[versal](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/53487/versal)** letter

Comment: _Versal letter_ is also used in a different sense, to refer to a capital letter in uppercase writing (as opposed to just a _capital letter_, which is used in regular, lowercase writing). A more common and unambiguous term is _drop cap_. They are also occasionally called _uncials_, but that is ambiguous as well, referring also to a specific all-caps type of script.

Comment: @Third News - _"Versal Letter"_ is a great takedown!  Not the phrase I was looking for, but better in its own right.  यhanks.

Comment: @ipso You don't mean a calligram?  It is a doodle, using letters that creates a visual image

Comment: [Calligram!!](https://www.google.com/search?q=calligram&tbm=isch) – I'm likin' it.

Comment: @ipso Is that it, or do I need to keep thinking? ;-)

Comment: That's not it.  But at this point I'm not sure if I'd recognize it; frankly.  I'm beginning to think it was more a nifty turn of phrase than an accepted term.  Also, today I find it paralyzingly ironic that my very question above is in fact embedded within exactly that which I'm talking about – albeit more straight-edge framing than organic flourishes.

Comment: For some reason I keep coming back to _“Red Letter Day”_ - which has nothing to do with it, but was apparently the first thing I associated to it in my mind.  I'd call off the horses, but I promise to come back here and update the thread if I come across it.  Thanks again.  (It's unfortunate I can't give the exact needed implementation online... for what we do is secret. ; )

Comment: @ipso Do you mean the box picture of your name?

Comment: You are looking for a scroll design with 2 vertical strokes

Comment: http://www.gograph.com/stock-illustration/decorative-lines.html

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for a *swash* set, especially in italic or script faces. These are fancy letters full of, well, swash. There are entire fonts meant for use inly for *versals*, those big letters at the start of a paragraph.

Another word sometimes used for versals is *lettrine* /lɛˈtriːn/, taken from the French and meaning per the OED:

> An initial letter, often decorated, and larger than the size of the text it accompanies.

In his *Elements of Typographic Style*, Robert Bringhurst glosses *lettrine* as:

> *Lettrine*   Literally, ‘a large letter’.  Synonym for *versal*.

And *versal* as:

> *Versal*   A large initial capital, either elevated or dropped. Also called *lettrine*.

He discusses these at some length, spending three pages on them in one instance and six in another, plus has several other mentions as well.  He writes that:

> Elevated caps are easier to set well from a keyboard, but drop caps have closer links with the scribal and letterpress tradition.  An the tooling and fitting of drop caps is something typographers do for fun, to test their skill and visual intuition. It is common practice to set the first word or phrase after the versal in caps, small caps, or boldface, as a bridge between versal and normal text.

Drop caps and illuminated versals have been used since before printing was invented, as this example form *The Book of Kells* shows:

[image: kells example]

These were even in the first printed book, and have been used ever since.  Here’s one from Gutenberg himself:

[image: Mainz psalter example]

[Here can be found a fine article](http://www.graphics.com/article-old/creating-drop-caps-adobe-indesign) on the various tricks that typographers do to create these gems in modern typesetting, alone with demos of how cool they can (and should) look when done right.  Here are some examples:

[image: drop cap example 1]

[image: drop cap example 2]

[image: drop cap example 3]

[image: drop cap example 4]

[image: drop cap example 5]

As Bringhurst says, they’re really neat, a chance for the typographer to show off his skills and judgement.

Comment: You're a workhorse around here, and it's appreciated.  Outstanding entry.  However the phrase (now I'm thinking a turn of phrase, not a single-word term) wasn't specific to the fist letter – at all – as much as incorporating doodles into the overall page (exactly as Josh nailed cold above) – and has very much to do with regular people writing letters vs. manuscripts or typeset which tries to mimic the thing.  The phrase I'm looking for surely was by someone who did not have _"flourished writing"_ in his toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

The term you're after is *illustrated capital* or *historiated initial.*